# Selenium Web-Driver : Can't Click on specific icon

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, xpath

I can't find the Element

url : http://money.cnn.com/2015/04/13/media/nate-silver-vox/index.html?iid=SF_MED_River

Element : "F recommended"

As it is a iFrame i tried to switch to other frame by using

```
WebElement frameID = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tag));

driver.switchTo().frame(tag);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: can't find `F recommended` in the source of the website. is that the id of the element?

Comment: Could you add more details of the Java code you are attempting to use to get Webdriver to find this element?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple iframes on that page. And most of them have ids, which is a good thing. So, you can do the following:

```
WebElement frameID = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the frame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameID);
//further commends
```

Comment: i have tried with id='facebook' but it didn't work
it get an error "no such element"

Comment: There is no iframe with id "facebook". Are you referring to the right tag?

Comment: what i want to do is to click on Element : "F recommended".
on clicking it it will give a pop up so i want to click on it and do some work on the new pop up .

Comment: The link you have provided does not have any element with text *F recommended*

Comment: it not a text it is a icon with "F recommended" on top . it is a Facebook recommended icon

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to fins the iframe as it doesn't have an ID:

```
WebElement frameFB = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'facebook')]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameFB);
```